# Правильная реализация MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня возник вопрос при освоении MVVM.
При таком подходе,когда существуют другие вспомогательные классы, к примеру классы сортировки данных или классы, которые изменяют в зависимости от данных интерфейс экрана (цвет или размер  элементов) нужно также все предоставлять через ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постарайтесь более лучше разобратся для чего-же нужен все таки MVVM. Вот вам ссылка [Полное понимание MVVM](https://habr.com/ru/post/338518/) на статью где если я не ошибаюсь идет цепочка статтей от самого простого понимания патерна до использования его в качестве построения полноценного GUI (Graphical user interface) приложения.
От себя отвечу на ваш вопрос, писать вью-модели для ваших моделей, необходимо лиш в том случаи если у вас есть клас (модель) который содержит данные и они изменяются посредством взаимодействия пользователя с интерфейсом. А если у вас есть клас который просто предоставляет необходимую функциональность, в вашем случаии например сортировка данных то для него воовсе не требуетсь никакая вью-модель, так так он не несет никаких данных. Тоесть пишите вью-модели для класов в том случаии если у него есть какие либо данные которые изменяются через пользовательский интерфейс вашего приложения.

Ну например у вас клас с полями name, surname. И в интерфейсе существуют соответствующие поля для ввода имени и фамилии. В таком случаи вам необходимо написать вью-модель, которая будет соеденять ваши данные: name, surname с соответствующими полями в интерфейсе для пользователя. Надеюсь мой ответ был полезен. За более подробной информацией перейдите по указанной ссылке.